# DSE nodes went down with ConfigurationException: Unknown data-center name ... passed to NetworkTopologyStrategy

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

My 3 cassandra staging nodes went down yesterday without starting as a result of below the logs excerpt in the system.log

```
INFO  [CoreThread-1] 2023-02-19 16:58:46,595  NodeSyncService.java:381 - Enabled Incremental NodeSync trackers for 10 tables in 394ms
ERROR [DSE main thread] 2023-02-19 16:58:46,697  CassandraDaemon.java:932 - Fatal configuration error
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Unknown data-center name 'Staging_cluster' passed to NetworkTopologyStrategy for keyspace 'system_auth': it is either unknown to the configured snitch, or has no active member (known DCs: {Staging_cluste: 3 nodes})
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy.validateExpectedOptions(NetworkTopologyStrategy.java:280)
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.AbstractReplicationStrategy.validateReplicationStrategy(AbstractReplicationStrategy.java:337)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.ReplicationParams.validate(ReplicationParams.java:94)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.KeyspaceMetadata.validate(KeyspaceMetadata.java:97)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.KeyspaceMetadata.<init>(KeyspaceMetadata.java:85)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.KeyspaceMetadata.create(KeyspaceMetadata.java:167)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspace(SchemaKeyspace.java:1154)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspaces(SchemaKeyspace.java:1769)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaManager.merge(SchemaManager.java:893)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaManager.mergeAndAnnounceVersion(SchemaManager.java:877)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.MigrationManager.lambda$announce$7(MigrationManager.java:350)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableFromRunnable.subscribeActual(CompletableFromRunnable.java:35)
        at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:2302)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableDefer.subscribeActual(CompletableDefer.java:43)
        at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:2302)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableConcatIterable$ConcatInnerObserver.next(CompletableConcatIterable.java:119)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableConcatIterable.subscribeActual(CompletableConcatIterable.java:47)
        at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:2302)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableDefer.subscribeActual(CompletableDefer.java:43)
        at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:2302)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableAndThenCompletable$SourceObserver.onComplete(CompletableAndThenCompletable.java:67)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableAndThenCompletable$NextObserver.onComplete(CompletableAndThenCompletable.java:99)
        at io.reactivex.internal.disposables.EmptyDisposable.complete(EmptyDisposable.java:68)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableEmpty.subscribeActual(CompletableEmpty.java:27)
        at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:2302)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableDefer.subscribeActual(CompletableDefer.java:43)
        at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:2302)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableAndThenCompletable$SourceObserver.onComplete(CompletableAndThenCompletable.java:67)
        at io.reactivex.internal.disposables.EmptyDisposable.complete(EmptyDisposable.java:68)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableEmpty.subscribeActual(CompletableEmpty.java:27)
        at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:2302)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableAndThenCompletable.subscribeActual(CompletableAndThenCompletable.java:35)
        at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:2302)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableAndThenCompletable.subscribeActual(CompletableAndThenCompletable.java:35)
        at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:2302)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletablePeek.subscribeActual(CompletablePeek.java:51)
        at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:2302)
        at io.reactivex.Completable.blockingAwait(Completable.java:1219)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.TPCUtils.blockingAwait(TPCUtils.java:87)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.finishJoiningRing(StorageService.java:1580)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:1456)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:933)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:852)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:419)
        at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:541)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate0(CassandraDaemon.java:754)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.access$100(CassandraDaemon.java:88)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon$3.run(CassandraDaemon.java:715)
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2023-02-19 16:58:51,490  Gossiper.java:1304 - InetAddress /10.**.***.*** is now DOWN
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2023-02-19 16:58:51,494  Gossiper.java:1349 - WRITING LOCAL JOIN INFO to [com.datastax.bdp.util.Addresses$Internode$AddressCacheManager@49298fe6, org.apache.cassandra.service.disk.usage.DiskUsageBroadcaster@131d9092, org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper$2@a50eda0, org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService@49544ce8, org.apache.cassandra.locator.ReconnectableSnitchHelper@4c87bc9b, org.apache.cassandra.service.LoadBroadcaster@33e12c99]
WARN  [GossipStage:1] 2023-02-19 16:58:51,532  NoSpamLogger.java:98 - Cannot answer echo request because this node is not yet initialized.
WARN  [GossipTasks:1] 2023-02-19 16:58:52,482  FailureDetector.java:294 - Not marking nodes down due to local pause of 70099399166 > 5000000000
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2023-02-19 16:58:56,710  DseDaemon.java:886 - DSE shutting down...
```

Kindly assist with a quick fix.

Comment: First of all, please don't just paste a giant error message.  We only need the relevant parts of it.  Also, Stack Overflow is meant more for programming questions.  Something like this should be asked on DBA Stack Exchange instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
ConfigurationException: Unknown data-center name 'Staging_cluster' passed
to NetworkTopologyStrategy for keyspace 'system_auth': it is either 
unknown to the configured snitch, or has no active member (known DCs: 
{Staging_cluste: 3 nodes})
```

Basically, the data center name defined in your `system_auth` keyspace definition does not match the data center name for any node in the cluster.

If you're using the `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch` check the cassandra-rackdc.properties file for the correct data center name.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that you configured the wrong DC for the `system_auth` keyspace. Notice the misspelling:

```
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: \
    Unknown data-center name 'Staging_cluster' passed to NetworkTopologyStrategy \
    for keyspace 'system_auth': it is either unknown to the configured snitch, \
    or has no active member (known DCs: {Staging_cluste: 3 nodes})
```

Your DC name is spelled incorrectly as `Staging_cluste` (missing `r` in the end) but you've configured the keyspace to be replicated to the `Staging_cluster` DC.

You will need to fix it with the CQL `ALTER KEYSPACE` command to get it working again. Cheers!